# How can I randomly generate 2D tile-based side-scroller terrain?

Tags: tiles, procedural-generation, tilemap, level-design, tile-bitmasking

**I want to randomly generate a map for a 2D sidescroller game using the following tileset:**
[image]

I have found a few great articles on the bitmasking process, for example:
http://www.angryfishstudios.com/2011/04/adventures-in-bitmasking/
http://www.saltgames.com/2010/a-bitwise-method-for-applying-tilemaps/

I like the idea of using a bitmask/tilemask instead of doing a huge if clause or switch statement.

However, I am having trouble visualizing the entire process and none of these articles talk about randomizing.

My tiles fit together in multiple different ways, not just one way as the tiles in the examples I linked seem to.

For example here are just a few examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since my tiles fit together in many different ways I don't think an 8 bit mask will work.
Therefore, I was thinking of using a larger bitmask. Something like char[8] or char[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad7me.png).

If someone could please show some pseudocode/examples of how the general algorithm would look, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the mask size would grow with increasing number of options - your own link http://www.saltgames.com/2010/a-bitwise-method-for-applying-tilemaps/ second part explains the main idea.

In essence, you'd have to enumerate X possibilities for each 'border' between tiles; in your particular example it looks like the "tile top/bottom" may be either (1) white (2) covered or (3) half-covered - which coincidentally matches the 'trinary' example given in the article.

But the masks would only help you restrict the tile possibilities to those that can be drawn, by itself it isn't a method that shows how to *generate* the actual maps in a sensible way.

Your particular tileset actually is quite restrictive - it describes only a single surface rising/falling, and at any 'integer-level' starting point you have only a few valid choices. For example, after tile #2 only tiles #1 or #8 are possible. You could simply move from left to right, making a list of which (few) tiles can come after the previous tile, and randomly choosing one of them.

Comment: I think this is the answer I am looking for, however it is still a little cloudy. Can you get a little more detailed, either in text or pseudocode on how the last part of your explanation would work? "You could simply move from left to right, making a list of which (few) tiles can come after the previous tile, and randomly choosing one of them."

Comment: For each tile type, have a list of what tiles are allowed after that - there are so few tiles, it can be quickly done manually.
The 'height' will change, fill everything below the new tile with #10s.

Comment: Ah so you are saying to use this method instead of the bitmasking?

Comment: Yes, bitmasking is useful if all the 2d content is meaningful, but your maps seem to be single-level, a horizontal surface of varying height.

Comment: That makes sense, the "mountains" will be of varying heights and will flow into each other. So essentially it will be a continuous mountain changes heights as you move along. Sort of like a cosine/sine wave that has random magnitudes at different points. Should I move left to right or top to bottom when generating the map?

Comment: How many different directions from the tile being placed would I need to check though when decided which tiles are allowed? I am thinking that I would need to check at least three directions (west, south west, and south)

Comment: You might treat '#3 on top of #1' as a single unit and move westward only at each step- checking at which 'partial height' you are after each column.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using a 1D Perlin or simplex noise function? There are a number of advantages to this, including:

1. Infinite (within the realm of floating-point precision), non-repeating terrain
2. Can be generated real-time (even in a shader, which is **fast**), or ahead-of-time and stored in textures, as in your example
3. Borders automatically match up as both Perlin and simplex are continuous.
4. Although the terrain itself is pseudo-random, it's easy enough to apply an envelope function or simply reduce the number of octaves in areas where you need flat areas or other specific terrain features that you need.

[See this link for a fairly thorough explanation](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/noise-part-1/creating-a-simple-1d-noise/) of 1D Perlin implementation.

An envelope is basically a scalar field or function that is multiplied with the noise function before saving or displaying your output.

[image]

(Initial image borrowed from the above-referenced article.)

In this example, the red line represents a piecewise function defined as

```
x < 0.3 : y = (0.3-x)/0.3)
x < 0.5 : 0
x < 0.7 : (x - 0.5) / 0.2
else    : 1
```

... which may be better defined using a smooth function. In this case, it just scales things down to 0 before the plateau, then back up to 1 afterwards.

**Update**

Here's an example of a 3D simplex "terrain" from one of my projects, with diffuse + specular lighting applied, generated entirely within a vert + tess + frag shader pipe. For your situation, I'd take a vertical slice out of this to get the terrain slope.

[image]

And a top-down orthographic view:

[image]

Comment: This is a technique for generating the actual tile images themselves?

Comment: @erebel55 Yes. You can use a 2D function to decide where (based on your example) to put different kids of plants within the image, and also to generate the sloping terrain. I've used this in 3D with great results.

Comment: It looks like an interesting method, I'm just not sure I want to go down this route as I have my images created already.

Comment: @erebel55 yeah, no reason to toss existing stuff if it's working for you.

Comment: Well I haven't got the random generation working yet, but I hope to ;) I gave you an up vote for this method thought, as it was interesting and I may use it some time in the future. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the update David, that looks really great. I think it is a little too complex for my little 2D game. However, It looks like a really useful 3D method.